# iPhone JSON Parsing

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios4, xcode4

I am new in iPhone app Development. 
I need some help... I want to parse some data (Banks Name) and show them into a `UITableView`. I'm using this code to Parse Banks Name which is in `JSON` Format :

```
     NSArray *atmDAta = [responseString JSONValue];
for (NSDictionary *dict in atmDAta) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [dict objectForKey:@"Name"]);
    [listOfItems addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"Name"]];
}
```

But when i try to show them in the the Table like this :

```
 cell.textLabel.text = [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
```

This will show me nothing in the table but NSlog is working and show me the banks name in the xcode log.  Please help.

Comment: Could you some more of your code? Is ListOfItem retained correctly? Does it have any item in it when you finished parsing? Or is the name you insert a empty string?

Comment: `code` NSMutableArray *listOfItems;

Answer (score 0):

Call   `[yourtable reloadData];` when you finished json parsing

Comment: Yeah i also do this like this [atmList reloadData]; but still have no any output

Comment: can you post some more code or paste the link from which you get the JSON

Comment: This is the [link](http://www.fourspan.com/atminfo/getatminfo.php?lat=47.822828&long=-28.44989) from where i parse the data

Comment: i did it and all the bank names are displaying in the tableview,your code of adding names to array is correct.Look at your tableview delegate methods , ithink something goes wrong there..

Comment: Are you initializing your array?.

Comment: Yeah i initializing array listOfItems...Plz Budy I realy need ur help

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this code for JSON Parsing

```
-(void)getLatestScore
 {
     SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];    

     NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://json-cricket.appspot.com/score.json"]];

     // Perform request and get JSON back as a NSData object
     NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

     // Get JSON as a NSString from NSData response
     NSString *str_Json_String = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

     // parse the JSON response into an object

     NSDictionary *dicCricketScore = [parser objectWithString:str_Json_String error:nil];

     lblDate.text = [dicCricketScore objectForKey:@"date"];
     lblMatch.text = [dicCricketScore objectForKey:@"match"];
     lblBattingTeam.text = [dicCricketScore objectForKey:@"batting_team"];
     lblScore.text = [dicCricketScore objectForKey:@"score"];
     lblSummary.text = [dicCricketScore objectForKey:@"summary"];
 }
```

From this code you will get Latest cricket score from JSON Parsing....

Comment: Hello Mehul Mistry...... Lot Of thanX for this but I already parse data into the label.... Now i only have to parse data and show it into the UITableView

Answer (score 0):

@Rocky Give this a try

Declare in .h
    NSArray *listOfItems;

```
@property (nonatomic, copy)NSArray *listOfItems;
```

and use this in .m

```
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSmutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:[atmDAta count]];
for (NSDictionary *dict in atmDAta) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [dict objectForKey:@"Name"]);
    if (![dict valueForKeyIsNull:@"Name"]) {
        [tempArray addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"Name"]];          
    }
}
self.listOfItems = [NSArray arrayWithArray:tempArray];
[tempArray release];
if([self.listOfItems count] > 0)
[yourTable reloadData];
```

Where I am using a Category

```
@implementation NSDictionary (KeyExists)

- (BOOL) keyExists:(NSString *) key {
    return [self valueForKey:key] != nil;
}

- (BOOL) valueForKeyIsNull:(NSString *) key {
    return ![self keyExists:key] || ((NSNull *)[self valueForKey:key] == [NSNull null]);
}
@end
```

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

After adding array you can do [listOfItems retain]